# distribution of ranges of numbers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, logical-operators

I am working on the distribution of number ranges such as 0-1, 2-3,4-6 and >=7 
I have the following data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['T1'] =[0,2,0,3,4,5,1]
df ['T2']= [1,2,3,0,2,3,3]
df['TT'] = df.T1+df.T2
```

I want to create a new column that will determine the ranges and I wrote as follow:

```
U0_1 = df ['TT']<=1
U2_3 = df ['TT']>1 & df ['TT']<=3
U4_6 = df ['TT']>3 & df ['TT']<=6
df ['TG'] = np.select([U0_1,U2_3,U4_6],['TG_0-1','TG_2-3','TG_4-6'],default = 'TG_7>=')
```

but it showed me the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Can I seek advice from you all?

Thanks,

Zep.

Comment: `U2_3 =( df ['TT']>1) &( df ['TT']<=3)` use `()`

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can using `pd.cut` , I think this is better way for this type of question

```
pd.cut(df.TT,[0,1,3,6,np.inf],labels=['TG_0-1','TG_2-3','TG_4-6','TG_7>='])
0    TG_0-1
1    TG_4-6
2    TG_2-3
3    TG_2-3
4    TG_4-6
5    TG_7>=
6    TG_4-6
Name: TT, dtype: category
```

For fixing your code add `()`

```
U0_1 = df ['TT']<=1
U2_3 = (df ['TT']>1) & (df ['TT']<=3)
U4_6 = (df ['TT']>3) & (df ['TT']<=6)
np.select([U0_1,U2_3,U4_6],['TG_0-1','TG_2-3','TG_4-6'],default = 'TG_7>=')
array(['TG_0-1', 'TG_4-6', 'TG_2-3', 'TG_2-3', 'TG_4-6', 'TG_7>=',
       'TG_4-6'], dtype='<U6')
```